# "Морские" ударения

Tags: жаргон, грамотная-речь, фонетика

Откуда появились разночтения в ударениях некоторых слов в моряцком жаргоне и в обычной речи. Почему моряки говорят "компАс", "МурмАнск" и "ГибрАлтар"?

Comment: Мурманчане НИКОГДА не говорят Мурманск.Никогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не "разночтения". Как и всякий профжаргон или арго, моряцкая речь содержит достаточно много специфических терминов и особенностей произношения. Среди прочего - названные вами. Вопрос "Почему?" здесь как-то не совсем уместен. Так уж исторически сложилось. В отдельных случаях можно указать, например, на бОльшее влияние одного из языков-источников, имеющего свои особенности произношения. В морской речи заметно влияние голландского на те слова, которые в общелитературный язык проникли из английского. Но это не наши случаи.

КОмпас - из немецкого Kompass, компАс - из итальянского соmраssо, там ударение на второй слог.

Касательно Мурманска могу сказать, что морское название ближе к "аборигенному", сами мурманчане чаще говорят именно МурмАнск. Хотя что на что тут повлияло - большой вопрос.

Про Гибралтар ничего сказать не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Потому же,  почему бухгалтеры говорят "КвАртал". Своеобразный жаргон на акцентологическом уровне. (Профессиональный жаргон - чтобы обособиться от других профессий).

Comment: Ну уж только бухгалтеры! Да (почти) все подряд так говорят, особенно если квартал - часть города.

Answer (score 0):

Слова, имеющие смещенное ударение, называются профессионализмами и считаются нормой для человека, связанного с тем или иным родом деятельности. Например, моряки говорят компАс, а работники горнодобывающей промышленности - рУдники.

Comment: Не совсем так. Слово со смещенным ударением - частный случай профессионализмов (профессионального арготизма), к которым также относятся специфические слова (всего более), фразеологизмы особого рода, слова с особенностями отдельных форм (склонения/спряжения) и т.д. Но вопрос был не в этом. Спрашивалось почему такое ударение, а не как оно называется.

Answer (score 0):

Не правда. Мурманчане всегда говорят МУрманск, от названия края

Answer (score 0):

Насчет ударения в слове "компас" могу привести свою точку зрения. Дело в том, что если обычного человека спросить, что такое компас, он скорее всего, представит себе туристический компас. А вот судовой компас по размерам и по устройству отличается от сухопутного. Поэтому, предполагаю, моряки/речники и называют это навигационное устройство по-разному. Вот по [этой](https://hostel-bereg.ru/registraciya/chem-otlichaetsya-morskoi-kompas-ot-suhoputnogo-kompasa-chto-takoe/) ссылке можно посмотреть, каковы отличия.